# How To Find Out Exact Angle Measurements of Object in Photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hi Folks: I am having a guitar body built and I am having no little trouble illustrating certain changes I'd like to see made. The builder is using a CNC and is loading in measurements that I've given him, but certain angles simply aren't looking right to me. I've attached a few photos which show-crudely-what I'm driving at. The top body is the guitar I am copying and the bottom a proto of the copy. It seems the point at which the downward slope begins should be lower on the proto-how do I express this precisely? Regards.[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The last photo I've uploaded is the model and above it is the proto. I am working on. What is

Comment: The last photo I've uploaded is the model and above it is the proto. Is there way to precisely superimpose this image ( all angles precise) so that he can see just what is wrong?

Comment: To me, that makes no sense.

Why can you not show pics of before and now and desired, then explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the guitar you are trying to copy, can't you at least lay the guitar on a sheet of paper and trace the outline of the body and send that to the machinist? Seems this would be the best method, short of sending the actual guitar to the machinist. Of course, if all you have is that photo of the original, things are different.

---

I'm not certain it's possible to extract **exact** measurements from a photo. You would first need something to reference for scale and there doesn't really appear to be much to meet that requirement in the photo. I suppose you could use the fretboard, given those are a standard width. But that's not really the issue here since I assume you know widths and heights and are more concerned with angles an curves.

You can attempt to get proper angles based on what you see.

Using the **Ruler Tool** and the **Measurement Log** (Window > Measurement Log):

[image]

With the **Ruler Tool** and your photo open click-drag along an angle to draw a line, merely eyeballing the angle in the photo. Once you get a line that resembles the angle in the photo click the **Record Measurement** button on the **Measurement Log Panel**. That will record data information regarding the line you drew, including the *angle* of the line in the furthest right column.

<sub>Large gif, may take a moment to load</sub>

[image]

The curves are another matter. I'm not certain Photoshop offers any ability to even guess at curve diameters. You would have to factor in all the various angles then mathematically determine proper curve radii.

Doing this shows the original having roughly a 64° and 129° angle on the right side, where as the CNC piece has roughly 62.5° and 132.5° angles.

<sub>(The photos can and *will* distort angles. The CNC piece isn't photographed straight on, there's an angle in the photo. So, the measurement will be skewed due to that.)</sub>

Again, this is all just *eyeballing* the photo. You might want to measure things multiple times then average those measurements in an attempt to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to superimpose the images over one another to see where there still needs to be adjustments.

[image]

However this is faulty since you need to get exact measurements to get anything concrete done. I'd try and look for specs or a large image size of the model you are trying to copy.

If you are set on this method you could use some digital measurement tools [like these french curves](https://growyourownclothes.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/imperial-french-curves1.pdf) to measure the edges.

Comment: Thanks Ovaryraptor! That Gif really helped. I'm trying to figure out ScreenPresso now. Regards.

Comment: @RonnieJackJones ScreenPresso is just the software I use to record not anything to do with measurements!

I'm using Photoshop to do the overlaying, you could also use GIMP as a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The copied body obviously isn't fully fixable because there's already taken off wood too much. The horns look out too short. If yo want to fix those parts which are still fixable you can make a cardboard model. Scale up the dimensions of your photo (you really should have a better image of the original, it's now too coarse; about 2mm/one image pixel), print it in overlapping parts, glue the parts onto a piece of cardboard and cut the excessive parts off. When handcrafting wood you need something into your hands and under your eyes, onscreen stuff  isn't enough.

Start with a test print of a simple shape to see if your printer have some scale error which must be taken into the account. A nearly maximum printable size rectangle with thin stroke is good.

Making the next right: You need proper CAD drawing. You can trace manually the photo in CAD software or in Adobe Illustrator and make a DXF. You surely know some of the dimensions, so the image can be scaled to exact size. From that drawing the CNC guy can make the right program which surely outputs what you have put into the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the guitar's shape precisely captured in a photograph, you need to be exactly parallel to the face of the guitar - not easy to do without a tripod and some measurement tools.

I would photograph the guitar against a gridded background where your lines are an exact distance apart - 1" or 1/4". Make sure that the camera is roughly centered over the bridge. Then, use the crop tool with "perspective" checked to crop the image to perfectly square dimensions. Resize the image to be the exact number of inches of grid paper to which you've cropped it, unchecking "scale proportionally" and manually entering the values. Straighten the image along the strings - Using the ruler tool, click and drag so that the line follows a string. Then press "Straighten" in the toolbar. Then resize the image again and set your PPI to 100 for simplicity's sake.

From there you should be able to take accurate measurements using the methods described in other answers.