# How can I create a template of this boat deck out of a photo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to be able to take a picture of the deck of a boat -- sample pics included. It is a flat plane. I want to be able to input the picture in my CAD program to create templates that I will cut.

[image]

## UPDATE

I've been doing my homework with all the information you gave me, I really appreciate the help. You know your stuff. This photogrammetry is confusing, so much info to learn especially for a rookie like myself. I've been playing around with Meshroom a little more just beacuse it looks more user friendly. I was able to put in some pictures into the program but now its giving me a error message.

[image]

Right now I'm using the prodim proliner for the measurements, but honestly for the price that it cost its not that easy to work with in some spaces and it still takes me some time to measure. I'm not happy with it at all. Do you think that Meshroom would be suitable for me? You also mentioned a CAD program with reverse engineering would work?

Comment: Are you asking if there's some automated way to detect the plane and extrapolate a path suitable for CAD from a photo, using Adobe Illustrator? Is the photo you intend to use the one attached or do you have a photo from above, of the *entire* deck? Typically a CAD application would be *much* better at this by merely inputting the actual measurements of the plane. Illustrator isn't really a CAD application, it's really more of a *drawing* application.

Comment: If you are asking if you can get measurements from a photo [**SEE HERE**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103573/how-to-find-out-exact-angle-measurements-of-object-in-photo)

Comment: No, but if you have several pictures from different location or beter yet hi def video, and one known dimension then yes

Comment: hello again! I wrote Ansys has high end CAD software SpaceClaim which is advertised to have some tools to fit normal cad surfaces to measured clouds or incomplete polygon meshes. See their introductory videos. I haven't such money they want. You can ask them to send a trial. If they see you are a serious custom candidate, you will get it. They do not take emtypockets to load their support system. Another high end 3D program Rhinoceros can do some reversing works from meshes, but I haven't it.

Comment: (continued) It shouldn't be impossible to make some local coordinate system and survey enough points one by one to get enough data of your surface.You can rent an industrial grade total station. Keeping the ship stable is a challenge.

Answer (score 4):

If your deck really is planar (I am not convinced of it) a single geometrically correct straight on the face photo would give the data. If you have say 4000 pixels wide photo and your deck is 4 meters wide in that direction, you could have resolution = 1 millimeter.

I'm sure you cannot get geometrically perfect images without lenses far beyond the reach of ordinary consumers. In addition, can you elevate the camera to high enough?

You must place some markers with known coordinates to have a possiblity to correct the geometry with software. If you can place the markers so that you know their places correctly, then you as well can survey the whole deck. The photo would still be a valuable tool, but all exact numbers are measured directly.

Do not expect Photoshop's photo merge or other photo stitchers make a geometrically correct composition of multiple shots. They fade seams, but right geometry reproduction isn't quaranteed.

Another possiblity is to use photogrammetry. Take a bunch of photos from different places with the same lens and let a photogrammetry program calculate the most probable surface. It can compensate lens errors automatically.

You get the surface as point cloud. Advanced photogrammetry programs also find a polygon mesh surface model for the photographed object.

You will need at least tens of photos and you must prevent all glosses and light variations. Your own shadow and glosses can make the result useless because they live as the camera moves. No constant light available? Then forget it.

High end CAD software have reverse engineering tools which fit ordinary 3D cad surfaces to the cloud or polygon surface model. Then you have normal cad style 3D model. See these links to examples of commercial applications:

https://www.agisoft.com

https://www.ansys.com/products/3d-design/ansys-spaceclaim/reverse-engineering

The presented stuff isn't freeware, far from it! Agisoft has low cost versions. Ansys hasn't. But they have trials. Do not expect you can save any remarkable amount of data from the trials.

Fortunately freeware exists, too. Check this comparison: https://all3dp.com/1/best-photogrammetry-software/

Reverse engineering capable CAD software such as Ansys provides probably is out of reach for most of us. But nothing prevents manual fitting a CAD model to the polygon mesh. I think you planned to do the same directly with a photo.

Some reasonably priced 3D modelling programs have mesh to NURBS surface conversion (or at least an attempt of it), but I haven't tried them. The conversion is far from trivial.